# Getting Random "out of bounds" Errors

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am adding features to a layer that has an extent the size of a state.  Randomly when I add a feature I get an "out of bounds" error.  As you can see in the snapshot below, I have added some lines in yellow.  When I try to add another one in between the yellow lines I get the "out of bounds" error.  Anyone know why i'm getting this random error?

Edit:  Ok, so I used ArcCatalog to re-create my extents.  This did not work either.  I could actually draw a box and a line inside the box would give me an error.  I then created a new MXD and added the layer and it is working fine.  I think there is something wrong with the MXD.  I have been using that same file for years, so I'm going to start working in the new file and see if I get the problem again.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange, Will. What have you tried so far? There's a technical article about this error that has some steps to try.  https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012800

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem sometimes as well. Not sure what causes it but my solution is to create a new line feature class and import all the fields from the original one. Start an edit session, then select all the lines from the original and copy/paste them into the new one.